# Scalaz 7: Idiomatic way of turning values in Either to plain values plus logged errors?

Tags: logging, scalaz, scalaz7

Given a function `f: A => E \/ B`, what is an idiomatic way to gather the `B` results for some list of `A`s while logging the `E`s?

I came up with the following (partially while [answering this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447222/scala-can-for-yield-clause-yields-nothing-for-some-condition/12447920#12447920)):

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
type Logger[+A] = Writer[List[String], A]

def logged[A, E, B, F[_]](f: A => E \/ B)(implicit FM: Monoid[F[E]], FP: Pointed[F]): (A => Writer[F[E], Option[B]]) = 
  (a: A) => f(a).fold(e => Writer(FP.point(e), None), b => Writer(FM.zero, Some(b)))

def listLogged[A, E, B](f: A => E \/ B) = logged[A, E, B, List](f)

type W[+A] = Writer[List[String], A]

def keepOdd(n: Int): String \/ Int = 
  if (n % 2 == 1) \/.right(n) else \/.left(n + " was even")

scala> val x = List(5, 6).traverse[W, Option[Int]](listLogged(keepOdd))
x: W[List[Option[Int]]] = scalaz.WriterTFunctions$$anon$26@503d0400

scala> x.run
res11: (List[String], List[Option[Int]]) = (List(6 was even),List(Some(5), None))

scala> val (logs, results) = x.map(_.flatten).run
logs: List[String] = List(6 was even)
results: List[Int] = List(5)
```

Is there a shorter / better / less restrictive / more general way?

Comment: I'm also interested in general insights on the ways you approach logging.

Comment: This would get more attention with a `scala` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `putWith` to write what to my eye is a more readable `logged` method:

```
def logged[A, E, B, F[_]: PlusEmpty: Pointed](f: A => E \/ B) = (a: A) =>
  WriterT.putWith(f(a).point[Id])(_.swap.toOption.orEmpty[F]).map(_.toOption)
```

I also think the `PlusEmpty` context bound on `F` looks a little cleaner than explicitly requiring `F[E]]` to be a monoid (it accomplishes the same thing, of course). It's a shame that the `.point[Id]` bit is necessary—that there's not a `Writer.putWith`—but beggars can't be choosers, I guess.

I'd also write `keepOdd` like this:

```
def keepOdd(n: Int) = Either.cond(n % 2 == 1, n, n + " was even").disjunction
```

Or at least use `n.right` instead of `\/.right(n)`, but that's just a matter of taste.