# global, default implicits in scalaz (scalaz7)

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7

When I code using Scalaz I often encounter problems, that there is no implicit in scope. I think there should be some default implicits somwhere in vast package scalaz, but either I don't know where or there are not any.

Suppose we want to `show` any `Any` in scalaz (I am using scalaz 7):

```
scala>     import scalaz._
import scalaz._

scala>     import Scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala>     {def a: Any = "sratatata"; a}.show
<console>:14: error: could not find implicit value for parameter F0: scalaz.Show[Any]
{def a: Any = "sratatata"; a}.show
^
```

That is not working becouse there is no implicit `Show[Any]` in scope.

Why Scalaz doesn't provide it? Is the good approach to use some global `Show[A]`? I mean something like this:

```
scala> implicit def anyShow[A] = Show.showFromToString[A]
anyShow: [A]=> scalaz.Show[A]

scala> {def a: Any = "sratatata"; a}.show
res0: scalaz.Cord = sratatata
```

I think the same touches `Equal`.

**EDIT**

I've tried as mentioned in answers to add `import scalaz.syntax.ShowSyntax` but that doesn't resolve my problem. See:

```
scala>     import scalaz._
import scalaz._

scala>     import Scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala>     import scalaz.syntax._
import scalaz.syntax._

scala>     import scalaz.syntax.ToShowOps
import scalaz.syntax.ToShowOps

scala>     import scalaz.syntax.ShowSyntax
import scalaz.syntax.ShowSyntax

scala>     {def a: Any = "sratatata"; a}.show
<console>:19: error: could not find implicit value for parameter F0: scalaz.Show[Any]
{def a: Any = "sratatata"; a}.show
```

Compiler still wants some `implicit scalaz.Show[Any]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Show` is only useful if you statically know the types; if you only know that you have an `Any`, just call `a.toString.`

If you want `Show[String]`, import `scalaz.std.string._`; for `Show[List[String]]` you would need to import *both* `scalaz.std.list._` and `scalaz.std.string._`.

Alternatively, you can import all the provided type class instances for the standard library with `scalaz.std.AllInstances._`.

This is explained step-by-step during @eed3si9n's excellent [Learning Scalaz](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz-day1) series.

There are also some good guides for Scalaz here:

[Good scalaz introduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863671/good-scalaz-introduction)